# Is CHKDSK a warning sign of failing drive?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, sata, chkdsk, disk-utility

This morning CHKDSK ran on its own during boot. It scanned 1 out of 3 HDDs in my PC. Is it a warning sign that that particular HDD is about die?

Comment: did it show any error's?

Comment: @LucPrevoo no errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chkdsk is automatically run on a few conditions, the most common being an improper startup/shutdown sequence.

In case you did this and forgot - Chkdsk can also be run on startup if you tried to run it when Windows was running, but Windows could not lock the disk. In this case, it will ask you if you want to run Chkdsk at startup, and if you click 'yes', then it will run before Windows starts.

Most likely it's the first case - an improper shutdown/startup.  But to answer your question, no, Windows/chkdsk does not know about the condition of your HDD before it runs.  It is running because it made some assumptions that a sequence of previous events may have left the data on your drive in an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 1):

A patition's dirty bit could get set because of both hardware ans software problems, although I wouldn't call it a problem if it was an isolated incident and Chkdsk didn't find any errors.

Keep in mind that Chkdsk only checks the file system, not the HDD itself.

To verify that your HDD Download a [S.M.A.R.T.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) tool (e.g., [Passmark disk checkup](http://www.passmark.com/products/diskcheckup.htm)). These tools report on several indicators of imminent failure, such as a high *reallocated sector count* (sectors that have been moved to the spare area due to read/write/verification errors).

Comment: What's a good value for `reallocated sector count`? This is mine's http://i.imgur.com/Go5xouP.png

Comment: The best value is 0 (i.e., no reallocated sectors). Your disk's *raw value* is 0, which is good. The *value* column holds some normalized metric; don't pay attention to it. The *status* column should say *OK* for all IDs. You can also perform a *Disk Self Test*.

Comment: Alright so I guess The HDD is still okay. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I you have no errors in your logfile I wouldn't worry to much. You can always try the command `chkdsk c: /f /r` (If C: is your drive letter) and check for error's

Answer (score 0):

Have you your event viewer for error corresponding to your hard drive? Bad drive sectors, inactivity, port failure and a variety of other errors in the **System** event viewer will tell you if a drive is failing aside from chkdsk reporting anything.